# Problema al hacer deploy en Vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, vercel

Hice un deploy de mi aplicación desde el repositorio en github a vercel.

Al ver la página no se cargan las imagenes, el error es

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
```

Entiendo que es un problema en la ruta de la imagen, estuve revisando, probando con ruta absoluta y relativa, en esta ultima la imagen no se logra visualizar en el local.

Dejo la estructura del proyecto y la ruta de la imagen si alguno me pudiera ayudar.

[image: Estructura]

[image: ruta]

A mi parecer es un problema con la configuración de vercel que esta tomando el root desde otro punto.

El tema es que no sé como solucionarlo, ademas de q en youtube no hay ningún video actualizado al respecto.

Comment: Es un proyecto de Next.js, o lo construiste con alguna otra herramienta?

Comment: Hola amigo, gracias por responder. Hoy justo lo solucioné, lo que hice fue pasar las imagenes a la carpeta public y colocar la ruta de esta forma '/static/img1.png'